# get value of selected row NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

how can i get value of selected row in NSTableView?

Comment: A little bit of context can go a long way...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cocoa follows the Model-View-Controller design pattern, so your reasoning as well as your own designs should as well.

You don't get any values from the table because you already have them in your model. Your controller (usually the data source) asks the table for its selected row index(es), then asks your model for the objects matching those indexes, then does whatever it needs to do.

Comment: That's great if you write tutorial apps with one class only. Real world applications have multiple tables in multiple classes attached to multiple different models. Non-trivial apps often route the action on a table to a different class than the one containing the table - it's often the only way to re-use code effectively, especially in apps with complex GUIs (e.g. image editing apps)

Comment: @Adam: Please demonstrate a situation wherein it's a good idea to ask the table *view* for its content, rather than the controller that supplies the content to the view. Be specific. Your argument flies in the face of years of good architecture and the statement that my description only works for tutorial apps, rather than "real world" apps borders on condescension. I maintain a highly complex scientific research application used by the National Institutes of Health and it manages to follow MVC for its many interacting tables just fine.

Comment: @Adam: If you're in the habit of jumping into code without working out a *complete* architectural design for the application *first*, it's easy to paint yourself into a corner and say "f*** it" and go anti-pattern - the equivalent of trampling over your fresh paint. Asking a table view for its contents is *never, ever, ever* a reasonable course of action in a proper MVC application, no matter how complex. If there's a table, there's a controller. THAT is the authority in this case.

Comment: @Adam: The fact that you talk about "multiple different models" demonstrates a flaw in your understanding of the design pattern. There is the model *layer*, the view *layer*, and the controller *layer*. The controllers would be responsible for merging sources from "multiple models" in the model *layer*. Their origin (eg, multiple Core Data stores and web services) is irrelevant to the design pattern; it's all the *model layer*, mediated to the views by the controller(s). The controllers can talk amongst themselves for the rest.

Comment: When a table tells you that something has been selected ... this is not the same thing as "asking a table view for its contents"; you need to know the identity of the selected thing (which, given that a tableview could be munging source data arbitrarily ... is NOT simply the row-number). e.g. I came here via Google because the notification in iOS (with the improved version of NSTableView) gives you enough data to work out which source item has been selected. The notification in NSTableView does not. It's frustrating that the top hit on Google is a legitimate question with non-answers.

Comment: @Adam: "How can I get the value of the selected row" is not the same as "How can I be notified of a row selection change" ... I think you're not reading the question or the "non-answer" very carefully.

Comment: It'd be lovely if the recent down-voter would care to explain the down-vote.

Comment: (PS wasn't me that downvoted - I agree that downvoters should explain why!)."I came here via Google because the notification in iOS" - I think this explains your confusion. iOS UITableView is *completely different from* OS X's NSTableView. The major problems in NSTableView (including the one listed in this question) are (presumably) why UITableView was redesigned/rebuilt from the ground-up. NSTableView - as recommended by Apple, using Bindings - is a lot nastier and harder to work with.

Comment: Well aware of the differences between NSTableView and UITableView (nearly 100% of my SO rep is through answering ObjC/Cocoa/Cocoa Touch/Xcode questions). I see no mention (or tag) of iOS on this question, though. Where are you pulling this quote from?

Comment: sorry, looks like a copy paste error + stupid mistake on my part - StackOverflow could do with a "quote comment X" system :(. Very hard to read multi-line comments. Suffice it to say: Apple's NSTableView is badly broken, has always been broken; Apple's 'bindings' system is even more broken; net effect: good OS X apps cannot use MVC, because Apple already broke it across the board. YMMV

Comment: just curious, what about when a NSTableViewCell is edited and the content is changed? Is there a method to see the content of the cell after the edit?

Comment: Your cell view should be calling some action against some target that updates your model and asks the table view to reload at least that cell if not the row or entire table (depending on your needs). A question about how to do this is best posted as a separate question with details specific to your needs.

Comment: If it's silly to ask the `NSTableView` what the row's object is, what do you make of the `objectValue` binding?

Answer (score 18):

By using `selectedRow`, [see here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstableview/1535010-selectedrow?language=objc):

```
@property(readonly) NSInteger selectedRow;
```

> The index of the last selected row (or the last row added to the
> selection).

You may also be interested in:

> –selectedRowEnumerator (deprecated)
>
> –numberOfSelectedRows
>
> –selectedRowIndexes "returns an index set containing the indexes of the selected rows"

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that you already have property named **tableView** and in xib you defined tableView with row **cellName**

```
NSInteger row = [tableView selectedRow];
NSTableColumn *column = [tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"cellName"];
NSCell *cell = [column dataCellForRow:row];
NSLog(@"cell value:%@", [cell stringValue]);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer - it may not be the "right" way to do things, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

To get selected row from table try this..

```
[tableView selectedRow];
```

To access the tableView value

```
[array objectAtIndex:[tableView selectedRow]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift2.0, this could help you:

```
  func tableViewSelectionDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
            let selectedTableView = notification.object as! NSTableView
            print(selectedTableView.selectedRow)
  }
```

Comment: Your answer is incomplete. Please, add more details regarding setup notification observing.

Comment: I was exactly looking for this in Swift 5. It works perfectly :)

Answer (score -1):

As we have all the value in our model, so we can only get the index of row and get the value using index. for e.g:

```
NSInteger row = [self.nsTableView selectedRow]; //here @property (weak) IBOutlet NSTableView *nsTableView;
NSString *cellValue = ObjectValue[row];// NSMutableArray *ObjectValue;
NSLog(@"%@", cellValue);
```