# get cell value from NSTableview

Tags: core-data, get, nstableview

I'm trying to get value from NStableView (i mean the core data value).
I read this: [get value of selected row NSTableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299066/get-value-of-selected-row-nstableview)

But i can't understand when this will be called?

i did the following:

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{

    NSInteger row = [contragentsView selectedRow];
    NSTableColumn *column = [contragentsView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"name"];
    NSCell *cell = [column dataCellForRow:row];
    NSLog(@"cell value:%@", [cell stringValue]);

    return 0;
}
```

but i don't know when this will be called.I nee to get the info when a button is clicked!

Comment: doing a "`return 0;`" from this function is not going to give you a valid cell.

Comment: I replaced it with return [cell stringValue];

Comment: But if the Log is not displayed in the console, the nothing will be returned too.

Comment: The above method will called when your tableView will populate the data

Comment: no, it does not! i have changed the code to: